# Joomla! Load jQuery library locally (without internet connection)

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla! template which uses jQuery. When working on my local machine connected to the Internet, the website works fine.

Without Internet, the page displays a blank page with a process bar in the center of the page.

Where is jQuery included in my template? How can I load it locally?

Comment: Hi "Funny stuff" is never really a good description of a problem :) can you clarify what happens, and show the `<head>` section of your web site? That's likely where jQuery is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code we use to ensure only 1 copy of jQuery is imported, and if it isn't, it should be loaded from a specific location:

```
<?php
  // load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
     $doc->addScript(JUru::root() . 'templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/js/jquery.js');
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Identify the name of the template you are using (check backend)
2. Go to /templates/YOURTEMPLATEFOLDER/index.php
3. Search for jQuery

You will find something like (maybe):

`$doc->addScript('http://www.example.com/jquery.js', 'text/javascript');`

1. Copy jQuery locally in the template folder (under js or javascript folder)
2. In index.php replace with the line (adapt where needed !!! ):

`$doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jquery.js', 'text/javascript');`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

I think I have to replace these three line. But with what? 
@Lodder

Comment: @MajorGeek - yes, you have to replace those lines and download jQuery and jQueryUI. Then replace the code that is already including them with the code from Valentin's answer or mine. They are both the same but the one I use ensures that it is not included twice, which prevents conflicts.